# OSSEC active response

Tags: security

I have been researching how to use OSSEC active response and it seems the only response commands I can find are firewall-drop.sh: and & mal-test . Is there a way to create custom responses?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom responses. Firewall Drop is just a shell script that they've created to block IP's matching the rules.

So the idea is, if ( rule == matched ) { run active-response }

If you go into the active-response directory, you will find firewall.sh. This can be replaced or you can create your own script there and that can work as an active-response.